# check if empty in php prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my prepared statement I can retrieve values returned by MySQL, but am unable to notify the user if MySQL does not return any data.

Below is the code of my prepared statement.

`$database` is an object of mysqli connection.

```
$stmt = $database->prepare($qryCallProc);
$stmt->bind_param('iss',$userId,$trendType,$university);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($param1,$param2);
while($stmt->fetch) {
    print_r($param1);
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

I tried even using below code after `$stmt->bind_result($param1,$param2)` but not useful:

```
if(!$stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r("there is no data");
} elseif (is_null($stmt->fetch())) {
    print_r("there is no data");
}
```

Am I missing something in my code or is there any other way where in I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `num_rows` first to check if your query yielded rows:

```
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($param1,$param2);
    while($stmt->fetch) {
        echo $param1;
    }
} else {
    // sorry no rows found
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works :) but only after  putting $stmt->num_rows after $stmt->store_result

Answer (score 4):

You must use `store_result()` before using `num_rows`

You could use `num_rows` first to check if your query yielded rows:

```
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($param1,$param2);
    while($stmt->fetch) {
        echo $param1;
    }
} else {
    // sorry no rows found
}
```